# Spring-Data Project is not receiving my Get/Post No entity found for query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I finished creating a simple Spring-boot project in which I can enter users and through the Get command it returns me the name (from a list of identical names) with the oldest entry date. Unfortunately, every time I ask for Get it returns this **ERROR**:

```
D:\>curl -G localhost:8080/demo/first -d name=Biagio
{"timestamp":"2020-10-05T08:52:34.741+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"","path":"/demo/first"}
```

In the Spring-Boot terminal I have this **ERROR**:

```
Biagio
2020-10-05 10:52:34.722 ERROR 8860 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No entity found for query; nested exception is javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query] with root cause
```

Even when I try to POST / add I get a message that it has saved in the DB but hasn't actually saved anything

Below I add all interested parties:

**AccessingDataMysqlApplication.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication
public class AccessingDataMysqlApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataMysqlApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

**MainController.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.rest;

import javax.persistence.NoResultException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserDto;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Transactional
//@RequestMapping(value = "/add/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@PostMapping(path="/demo/add")
public String addNewUser(@PathVariable("name") String name, @PathVariable("email") String email,
@PathVariable("surname") String surname) {

UserDto n = new UserDto();
n.setName(name);
n.setSurname(surname);
n.setEmail(email);
userService.create(n);
return "User Saved in DB";
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
//@RequestMapping(value = "/fetchUser/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@GetMapping("/demo/first")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> fetchUser(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
System.out.println(name);

try {
UserDto namefound = userService.findFirstByName(name);
System.out.println("Name found");
ResponseEntity<UserDto> user = new ResponseEntity<UserDto>(namefound, HttpStatus.OK);
return user;
} catch(NoResultException ne) {
System.out.println("User not found");
return new ResponseEntity("User not found with name : " + name, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}

}
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserDto;
@Service
public interface UserService {

    UserDto findFirstByName(String name);
    
    void create(UserDto user);
        
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserDto;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserEntity;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.repo.UserRepository;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.util.UserMapper;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public UserDto findFirstByName(String name) {
        UserEntity entity = userRepository.findFirstByName(name);
        return mapper.toDtoMapper(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void create(UserDto user) {
        UserEntity entity = mapper.toEntityMapper(user);
        userRepository.create(entity);
    }

}
```

**UserMapper.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.util;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserDto;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserEntity;



@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {   
    
    public UserEntity toEntityMapper (UserDto user);    
    public UserDto toDtoMapper (UserEntity userEntity);
    
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.repo;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserEntity;


@Repository
public interface UserRepository {
    UserEntity findFirstByName(String name);
    void create(UserEntity entity);
    
}
```

**UserRepositoryImpl.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.service;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserEntity;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.repo.UserRepository;

@Component
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    private final EntityManager em;

    public UserRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.em = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity findFirstByName(String name) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<UserEntity> criteria = builder.createQuery(UserEntity.class);
        Root<UserEntity> root = criteria.from(UserEntity.class);
        criteria.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("name"), name));
        criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get("timestamp")));
        TypedQuery<UserEntity> query = em.createQuery(criteria).setMaxResults(1);
        return query.getSingleResult();

    }

    @Override
//  per la creazione//
    public void create(UserEntity entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
    }

}
```

**UserDto.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class UserDto implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7621330660870602403L;
    /**
     * 
     */

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    private Timestamp timestamp;
    private String email;
    private String surname;

}
```

If you need also I could provide User.java and the pom file, but the pom has no problems as the dependencies are all correct.

Comment: I would request use postman or other tool to test instead of curl and as per your error at service class in CriteriaBuilder, UserEntity is not found. it seems issue in entity manager. you could found exact issue but proper dubug or TDD code. Other option is use CrudRepository or JpaRepository

Comment: You are not using spring data jpa properly. You should use `JpaRepository`. Also i see you are using `@PathVariable` in POST request to send multiple user fields in URL . Why don't you use `@RequestBody`

Comment: Hi Ajit!  you're right actually it's better to use @RequestParam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `create` method is invalid. And because of this you cannot actually retrieve some data.
You only called `persist` method, but you also need to call `flush` to actually write this to DB. Code snippet could look like this:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void create(UserEntity entity) {        
    if (!em.contains(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Evg!  would you be kind enough to show me where to put this piece of code ??

Comment: Sure, it should be placed inside your `public void create(UserEntity entity)` method in your `UserRepositoryImpl` class.
p.s. Just updated the answer.

Comment: When I use your method I get out of this error: ```.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead```

Comment: Okay, I will update the answer again then, check it out. Point here is to delegate transactions handling to the Spring instead of manual handling.

Comment: Even inserting the change does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Well, you get no result in your query but force one with `getSingleResult()`. You can use a [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) from Spring, that's a bit easier.

Comment: Hi Milgo!  Thank you very much for your reply, unfortunately I cannot use Crud for various requirements that have been imposed on me